# Does ARC guarantee that an object is dealloc'ed instantly once the last strong reference is gone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

In particular, would this kind of code always work as intended (where MyResourceGuard is an object that locks an exclusive resource in its init method and frees the lock in its dealloc method):

```
NSLog(@"About to capture some exclusive resource.");
{
  MyResourceGuard* guard = [MyResourceGuard new];
  // Do something with the exclusive resource here.
}
// guard is out of scope, therefore its dealloc should have
// been called right away and the resource should already
// be free again at this point.
```

I have read in books and blogs that in contrast to e.g. Java garbage collection, ARC destroys objects as soon as the reference count decreases to zero (and not at some time of its own convenience), but I haven't read this in any official documentation by Apple. And if that were true, why would we ever need the new @autoreleasepool keyword introduced with ARC?

From debugging, I have always seen the object dealloc'ed immediately, except when an exception is raised in a try-catch-block, in which case dealloc actually was *never* called (is that a Mac bug, or just one of these scary Objective C oddities?).

Comment: "And if that were true, why would we ever need the new @autoreleasepool keyword introduced with ARC?" Because autorelease is still needed (since you need to be able to pass objects you just created out of e.g. accessors), and the compiler needs to be wise to autorelease semantics.

Comment: *…an exception is raised in a try-catch-block, in which case dealloc actually was never called* -- ARC + ObjC will not save you here. that object will leak (unless ARC decided an autorelease pool was a better place for it). ARC + ObjC will not generate code for cleanup when unwinding. ARC + ObjC++ will do a little cleanup (not all). it's best to avoid exceptions in ObjC :)

Comment: Note that you should not be using try-catch blocks for anything but documenting fatal crash states within your application;   exceptions are not to be treated as recoverable.

Comment: @Jesper: Under ARC, passing an object out of the accessor would increment the reference count because of the additional outside reference. Once that outside reference ceases to exist, the object would be deallocated; nothing to do with autorelease pools.

Comment: @AndreasZollmann: Assuming both ends are ARC, yes, and thanks to the `objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue`/`objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` interplay. You can't make that assumption if any end is manual retain/release, so autorelease is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You don't have deterministic scope based destruction of ObjC objects as your example shows.

For example, this program could result in deadlock:

```
{ MyResourceGuard* guard = [MyResourceGuard new]; }
{ MyResourceGuard* guard = [MyResourceGuard new]; }
```

The best you can do if you need this functionality is to use C++ types ([SBRM, RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) -- also available in Objective-C++ (but not applicable to objc objects).

It comes close, but you just have to wait until the reference count reaches zero for `-dealloc` to be called, and that's why the guarantees are off (*usually != always*). This problem is actually quite similar to why you would never rely on or use `-retainCount` (where it is available). Examples: Autorelease Pools, exceptions, changes to the runtime or ARC generated code, compiler optimizations, using implementations which have different code generation flags could result in the life of the objc object being prolonged beyond the scope.

**Update**

The [whole page on ARC at clang's site](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#optimization.precise) is a good read on the subject -- including details, guarantees (and lack of guarantees), but in particular:

> 6.1. Precise lifetime semantics
>
> In general, ARC maintains an invariant that a retainable object
>   pointer held in a __strong object will be retained for the full formal
>   lifetime of the object. Objects subject to this invariant have precise
>   lifetime semantics.
>
> By default, local variables of automatic storage duration do not have
>   precise lifetime semantics. Such objects are simply strong references
>   which hold values of retainable object pointer type, and these values
>   are still fully subject to the optimizations on values under local
>   control.
>
> Rationale: applying these precise-lifetime semantics strictly would be
>   prohibitive. Many useful optimizations that might theoretically
>   decrease the lifetime of an object would be rendered impossible.
>   Essentially, it promises too much.
>
> A local variable of retainable object owner type and automatic storage
>   duration may be annotated with the objc_precise_lifetime attribute to
>   indicate that it should be considered to be an object with precise
>   lifetime semantics.
>
> Rationale: nonetheless, it is sometimes useful to be able to force an
>   object to be released at a precise time, even if that object does not
>   appear to be used. This is likely to be uncommon enough that the
>   syntactic weight of explicitly requesting these semantics will not be
>   burdensome, and may even make the code clearer.

Even if you do use the `objc_precise_lifetime` attribute, it will apply to reference count operations for that strong local *variable* -- not the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why could the release ever get deferred under ARC due to an autorelease pool? And is there any currently existing compiler optimization that could cause a deferral? Regarding code generation, I assume you are referring to accidentally generating non-ARC code?

Comment: a) that is the purpose of an autorelease pool. objects are added to the pool (when autoreleased or an object referencing them is added). then all release messages are sent when the pool is destroyed. b) you must also consider the runtime. even if you try, there is no guarantee -- will update the answer with a reference shortly. c) nope. the compiler uses a handful of C functions to perform reference counting. the exact details, and how the runtimes handle it, are subject to variation. the obvious case right now is the difference between MRC and ARC (cont)

Comment: (cont) example: ARC has the ability to pass reference of return values to the caller, while MRC does not. there are also cases where ARC uses autorelease. the runtime is even free to use autorelease. the compiler also reserves the ability to order instructions as it sees fit. neither the language, runtime, or compiler guarantee precise lifetimes. because you are fighting a few levels of abstraction, you cannot reliably determine the sequence point when an object will be deallocated (or even messaged `release`, for that matter) in all cases.

Comment: @AndreasZollmann some guarantees are made -- you would enjoy this for a lower level understanding of ARC: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score 0):

this kind of code will always work. (or at least as long as ARC works like it does right now)
A small example for object-lifecycle in ARC:

```
{
    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] init]; //object allocation
    a = nil; // object is deallocated as it was created in this scope

    NSString *b = [NSString string]; //method call which returns an object (always autoreleased)
    b = nil; // object is not deallocated as it was not created in this scope and is therefore autorelased
}
```